# Bug in component input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[image]

I need to customize Ant Design's Input Number field. For the currency field to be in the format (currency)
    eg: R $ 9.800,99.

I used Intl but NaN is returning. How can I resolve this bug?

Related link:

- [Ant InputNumber API: formatter](https://ant.design/components/input-number/#API)
- [JS Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Click: [Here](https://8pwvi.csb.app/)

Sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-hamilton-8pwvi

```
const MyInput = () => {
  const handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <InputNumber
        name="topText"
        style={{
          width: 400,
          marginRight: "1rem"
        }}
        formatter={value => new Intl.NumberFormat("pt-BR", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "BRL"
          }).format(value)
        }
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="contain-all">
      <MyInput />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Can you please post your code as text instead of image? Thanks!

Comment: It seems good, looks like the value been passed to this component was empty

Comment: Don't you need to parse value to number before operating on it ?

Comment: @norbitrial I added the sandbox link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your link of ant design example and I got to know that you need a `parser` aswell. So I create an example of working code for you. here is the code:

```
  <InputNumber
    name="topText"
    style={{
      width: 400,
      marginRight: "1rem"
    }}
    formatter={value => `R$ ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}
    parser={value => value.replace(/[R]\$\s?|(,*)/g, "")}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
```

Here is the **working example** of the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-morning-expib

Since its numeric type field so you can increment or decrement the value using the arrows

Comment: First of all I'd like to thank. But unfortunatily it's not working for me.

Comment: Yes I did. when using keyboard number NaN appears in the field

Comment: Seems like it is not attending this format  "R$ 9.800,99 ".  Furthermore I can't type cents.

Comment: I was able to have this format R$ 111.666,666. Can you specify all the formats you want?

Comment: I have updated the regex according to the format you posted in the last comment. See the codesandbox link